# iPhone App in wrong orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, orientation

My App is a portrait and landscape right only App. So it starts in portrait, then you tilt into landscape mode. Everything is fine. When I now double press the home button the task switcher UI appears in landscape mode as well.

My problem starts after that. When I now go back to portrait and then back to landscape the system now recognises my app as portrait only. When I hit the task switcher the UI is portrait as well and the app gets kicked into portrait (I'm holding the device in landscape).

I instantiate a TabBarController in

`override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval)` for `UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait`

in my landscape view controller and I'll dismiss the portrait controller in the same method (in my portrait view controller) when rotating back to landscape.

When a notification appears (any push/message) in landscape mode the view controller jumps into portrait mode and when it disappears back into landscape mode.

I'm using the latest iOS (8.4) and Xcode (6.4) version.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks